# Dell Precision m3800 wifi "Hardware Disabled"

Tags: wireless, dell

Network applet lists wifi as "Hardware Disabled." If I go to *Software & Updates > Additional Drivers* it indicates

```
Broadcom Corporation: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Adapter. This device is using an alternative driver
```

The following option is checked *"Using Broadcom 802.11 Linux STA wireless driver source from bcmwl-kernel-source (proprietary)."*

If I run

```
lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network
```

I get:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0019]
Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
Region 0: Memory at eca00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
Region 2: Memory at ec800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

1. <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd> has no effect. There are not wireless options in the BIOS I can't find it.
2. I have purged and reinstalled bcmwl-kernel-source to no effect.
3. When I run rfkill list I get:

   ```
   0: phy0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
   1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: yes
   2: nfc0: NFC
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no
   ```

   So I run `rfkill unblock 1` to no effect.
4. I have tried this to no effect:

   ```
   cd /etc/modprobe.d/
   mkdir tmp
   mv iwlwifi.conf tmp
   ```

I have poked other around `/etc/modprobe.d` files to no effect. Another files I touched I changed back to their original state before trying something else.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hard-blocked typically means that your wireless is switched off. You likely have a hardware switch or keyboard combo that will turn it on. Check the manual for your system for more information.

Comment: You may find these helpful: http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftopics-cdn.dell.com%2Fpdf%2Fprecision-m3800-workstation_Owner%2527s%2520Manual_en-us.pdf&ei=rPYjVY7VB4flsAXUyIKICw&usg=AFQjCNFKtYuY_r8iKvY7R-PHS7tOQIxprw&sig2=a0E6NFYuZZhK9GA9MGh8VQ&bvm=bv.89947451,d.b2w and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2245434

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. You might notice the keyboard combo suggested in the manual and solution in that ubuntuforum are fixes I have already tried.

Comment: Do any of the other Fn key combinations function? Have you checked the antenna leads to the wifi card as shown on  page19 of your manual? does the device status for wifi as mentioned on page 46 light up?  I still haven't found the page with the wifi switch in your manual yet, so I'm afraid I didn't take Fn-PrtScrn as gospel. What page was that?

Comment: Is this your keyboard? http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN288770/EN

Comment: Yeah, that's my keyboard. The other Fn key combos work. Wifi device status indicator does not light up.

I have not checked the antenna leads. I don't have screwdriver small enough to take bottom panel off.  Machine is weeks old. Wifi worked until I started tweaking my system. 

Running Dell's preboot hardware diagnostic tool indicates the following:
Wireless Switch = Off
Wireless LAN = Disabled
Bluetooth = Disabled
Wireless LAN = Not Installed

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Fortunately I planned to dual boot (just in case) for a while. When I boot into Windows and do fn+PrtScr (wifi button), the wifi turns on, then works in Linux too. Not sure why, but the hardware button on the keyboard doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score -2):

I have the exact same problem on my computer (also Precision M3800). The above trick with dual booting to Windows does not work - perhaps it is specific to the version of Windows on dual boot, I have 8.1. But this may be a partial solution: there is now a driver for the Dell airplane mode switch as of kernel version 4.2.